# xtext, modify outline tree string

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

this is my `xtext` outline:

[image]

I would like to name by my self the unnamed fields.

this is my outline tree provider code, it's not a final version :

```
class MyDslOutlineTreeProvider extends DefaultOutlineTreeProvider {

  def _createChildren(DocumentRootNode parentNode, Script test) {
       test.includes.forEach[v| createNode(parentNode,v)] 

       //test.assignments.forEach[a | createNode(parentNode,a)]
       test.tests.forEach[t|createNode(parentNode,t)]
  }
  def _createNode(IOutlineNode parentNode, Include modelElement) {      

  }
  def _createNode(IOutlineNode parentNode, Test modelElement) {
      // print ("RUN")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the displayed texts not in your `OutLineTreeProvider`, but in your `LabelProvider`.
You can find examples in the [Xtext documentation about LabelProvider](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.xtext.doc%2Fcontents%2F310_eclipse_support.html&cp%3D100_1_6_0_0&anchor=eobject-label-provider) (see at Xtext Documentation -> Eclipse Support -> Label Provider).